# Correct punctuation when specifying translations

Tags: punctuation

When writing a list of railway stations in both Japanese and English, which kind of punctuation should be used to indicate a translation? I was reading this article and was wondering if the same rules apply in Japanese.

[Quotation Marks: How To Use Them Correctly (With Examples) | Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/quotation-marks/#:%7E:text=The%20first%20sentence%20contains%20a%20direct%20quote%2C%20a,Quotation%20marks%20are%20used%20only%20with%20direct%20quotes.)

In this example image: [Chiyoda line map](https://maps-tokyo.com/maps-tokyo-metro/chiyoda-line-map)

Have I used the correct punctuation marks

> 北千住『Kita-Senju』
>
> 綾瀬『Ayase』（終点）

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, its depends on the context where the translation occurred.
In general use like emailing, I saw Japanese people tend to use this brackets「」called 鉤括弧 to explain the translation in english to japanese person.
But there are case my Japanese coworker use this brackets () too.

Answer (score 1):

It depends (on everything). If you are writing a document in which you want to give the station names both in Japenese script and in Roman letters (not "English"), then if the document is in English, you should use the punctuation rules of English. If the document is in Japanese, German, or anything else, you use the rules for that language. The problem is that punctuation "rules" are really just conventions, and never cover things like foreign script. So you can do anything reasonable. Of course, if you are not writing a "document" as such, just making a list of Japanese station names in two scripts, you can choose any reasonable format.

Your choice does not seem very reasonable. The 'kagi' quotes 『』 are definitely "Japanese writing", and not really suitable for Roman letters. You are very likely to find odd cases, such as a descender on the last letter, where they really look peculiar, since they are originally meant to outline the corners of a box surrounding the Japanese characters. 『漢字仮名交じり』 (This problem might be less prominent if you use a Japanese roman font, because it will have mutilated descenders. So it all depends if this is a text in Japanese or not.)

Comment: Would you say that parentheses `(` and `)` would be more reasonable?

Comment: You first need to explain: is this embedded in a Japanese document, embedded in an English document, or something else? (Yeah, sure, ordinary -- not ''zenkaku''! -- parentheses do at least fit with English text.)